# How can i make my app be classed as Low Battery usage?

Tags: android, android-location

I have implemented Google - Fused Location Provider. Like below code...

```
LocationRequest locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    sendLocationUpdate(location,this);
    locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(locationListener);
    locationclient.disconnect();
 }
};
locationrequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, locationListener );
```

but it still shows as a High battery use app. Can any explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I am also trying to figure out how to do! I have a question open with a 50 points bounty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitely set the GoogleMap.setLocationSource.

Here is an example: [Android: Google Maps location with low battery usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage)