# My location and marker have different locations

Tags: android, google-maps

Why does my location and marker have different locations? Before adding the marker I click on the floating button and when I click that, I call `getLatitude` and `getLongitude` from `LocationManager`. It's similar to when the is map ready and move camera so I think the marker and mylocation must be the same:

[image]

This is my code:

```
private class MyLocationListeners implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = null;
        latitude = null;

        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged1: " + longitude);

        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged2: " + latitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Code where I set `MyLocationListener`:

```
locationListener = new MyLocationListeners();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        5000,
        10,
        locationListener
);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you are setting the `MyLocationListeners`?

Answer (score 0):

The [My location layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer) uses it's own location provider that is not the Fused Location Provider nor the Location Manager. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource):

> A GoogleMap object has a built-in location provider for its my-location layer, but it can be replaced with another one that implements this interface.

Also, the My location layer, the Fused Location provider and the Location Manager can get different locations (it depends on the provider, the GPS and network availability, ...).

You can replace the default location provider for the my-location layer using the `GoogleMap.setLocationSource` method.

Comment: can you explain detail for me? what must I replace in my code

Comment: Here you can find a very googd example that uses fused location provider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage