# My-location layer and location from Location listener differ

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

For google maps I have set option `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` and it draws my location on map, but the location I get from `LocationListener` is different. The marker I add from `onLocationChange(Location location)` and the my-location (the blue dot) are not always in the same place.

**Location updates:**

```
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Location getLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
                    (LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            try {
                if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2 * 1000, 5, this);
                }
                if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2 * 1000, 5, this);
                }
            } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException | SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng objLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(objLatLng));
    }
```

So my question is how can I get the location source of the my-location layer or how to change my location update request so that the have same locations?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394172/android-my-location-and-marker-have-a-different-location/38395765#38395765

Comment: I am aware that it uses build in location provider, but I want to access it or know how its configured.

Comment: It uses it's own implementation and it's not guaranteed to be the same between implementations, so as I state in that answer, the best option is to replace the default location provider for the my-location layer using the `GoogleMap.setLocationSource` method

Comment: I don't want to replace with my location source as the default one looks smoother, but I'll do it later if I cant get the default one.