# My setLocationSource() method throws NPE

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, google-location-services

I want to implement `setLocationSource()` to handle the battery High of use, i tried from the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource) and search for samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108326/android-google-maps-location-with-low-battery-usage), but i get `NullPointerException` on

```
mMap.setLocationSource(this);
```

what am i missing..

I have long code..this is just related code i display..not all code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationSource,
        LocationListener {
and so on...
```

..

```
private OnLocationChangedListener mMapLocationListener;
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

...

```
    @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            mMap.setLocationSource(this);
            mMap = googleMap;
and so on....
```

...

```
private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(8000)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

...

```
@Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener) {
        mMapLocationListener = onLocationChangedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        mMapLocationListener = null;
    }
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        isOnline();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST, this);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Koneksi ke Google API Terganggu, Coba lagi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Terhubung dari Google Play Services.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }
        if (mMapLocationListener != null) {
            mMapLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.setLocationSource(this);
and so on....
```

Comment: holy mother.... i must have tired, i did not notice such that error..haha.. thank you so much, i need to sleep from long hours of code.. it works.